# How do I display tags for future posts in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I need to display all tags for future posts (e.g for a events). I tried with arrays in `wp_tag_cloud` function, but it's not working.

```
wp_tag_cloud(array('post_status' => 'future'));
```

I tried few more things, but it seems like there is no solution in easy way to display for future posts. Thanks for the any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember seeing this issue somewhere. In fact, they ended up doing it all by hand. Would be something like:

```
// Build tags array

$tags = array();
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_status' => 'future',
    'numberposts' => -1
));
foreach ($posts as $p) {
    foreach (wp_get_post_tags($p->ID) as $tag) {
        if (array_key_exists($tag->name, $tags))
            $tags[$tag->name]['count']++;
        else {
            $tags[$tag->name]['count'] = 1;
            $tags[$tag->name]['link'] = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);
        }
    }
}

// Show tag cloud

foreach ($tags as $tag_name => $tag) {
    echo '<span class="tag" style="font-size:' . $tag['count'] . 'em;">' .
        '<a href="' . $tag['link'] . '">' . $tag_name . '</a></span>';
}
```

You'll probably want to write a compare function to use with [`array_usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to order the `$tags` array alphabetically or by tag count.

Hope it helps.

Comment: vinicius, thank you for the answer, but I didn't get anything with this code (not even with publish post status). array_usort is not important to me right now. can you check one more time is everything ok? Thanks, this mean a lot to me and I'm little bit surprised that I can't find anything about that issue :/

Comment: @DosadanDan Sorry. It was from brain to keyboard, I didn't tested it. Fixed the function name, parameters and object attributes. The logic is exactly the same.

Comment: how can I thank you man? :))) I get publish and future posts, but never mind. I can live with that too. thanks

Comment: @DosadanDan Are you sure? `'post_type => 'future'` shouldn't give you published posts. Also, note that you can have tags assigned to future and past posts too, so maybe you're seeing past tags that are assigned to future posts. If you like the solution, just upvote it and we're fine. =D

Comment: sorry, I don't have enough reputation :/

Comment: @DosadanDan I didn't notice. Don't worry. =D